# How to change react-bootstrap carousel animation ton fadein?

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

I want to change Carousel animation to fade-in/out or another animation. But I wasn't able to find something in docs.

Can someone help or suggest another Carousel library for reactjs except react-slick.

```js
class Banner extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      direction: null,
    }
  }

  handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
    this.setState({
      index: selectedIndex,
      direction: e.direction
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Carousel activeIndex={this.state.index} direction={this.state.direction} onSelect={(i, e) =>this.handleSelect(i, e)}>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src={images[0]}/>
            <Carousel.Caption>
              <h3>Second slide label</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </Carousel.Caption>
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src={images[0]}/>
            <Carousel.Caption>
              <h3>Third slide label</h3>
              <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
            </Carousel.Caption>
          </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you using fade property and set it to true

```
fade={true}
```

Then override carousel-item and carousel-item.active classes

```
.crousel-item{
        opacity:0;
        transition: opacity 1s !important;
      }
      .carousel-item.active{
        opacity:1;
        transition: opacity 1s !important;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `fade={true}` to the Carousel component. Or if you want it to slide, add `slide={true}`. That's it!

```
<Carousel style={{ position: 'relative' }} fade={true}>
    `Carousel Items code...`
<Carousel/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is asking for other references to such libraries [react-responsive-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel) would be a great fit. This has a lot of customizations
on

- autoplay,
- swiping,
- keyboard navigations,
- custom animations
- custom thumbs, arrows, indicators etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the `fade` class:

```
    <Carousel className="fade" activeIndex={this.state.index} direction={this.state.direction} onSelect={(i, e) =>this.handleSelect(i, e)}>
```